# How to plot from .txt file

Tags: python, text

I have a .txt file and would like to plot the data.

Here my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('/home/tont_fe/Desktop/Extra_for_paper/Lifbase OH emission2.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    item = [float(item) for item in x]
    y = [(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
```

I receive the following error:

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 281,2

example of data:
281,228 0,01097

281,2289    0,0096

281,2297    0,00888

281,2306    0,00883

281,2315    0,00932

281,2324    0,01008

281,2333    0,01062

281,2341    0,01058

281,235 0,01013

281,2359    0,00981

281,2367    0,01013

281,2376    0,01141

281,2385    0,01377

Comment: Replace the commas with periods!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a `string` containing `,` to `float`. That's why the error!

Remove the `,` and then convert to `float`.

```
with open('/home/tont_fe/Desktop/Extra_for_paper/Lifbase OH emission2.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    
    # This line will remove ',' from each string of x
    x = [i.replace(',', '') for i in x]
    
    item = [float(item) for item in x]
    y = [(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
```

Comment: unfortunately i still cannot rank the answer I do not have enough reputation but the answer is accepted I think :) thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

`ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 281,2`

Float is excepting `.` but got `,` which caused `ValueError`. You might either replace `,` using `.` before feeding it into `float` or harness [locale built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/locale.html) following way:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE')  # I use Deutschland but can be any country using , in floats
value_str = "281,2"
value_float = locale.atof(value_str)
print(value_float)
```

output

```
281.2
```